# What the meaning of `text[..., :5]` in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused about one code line in [Github](https://github.com/lucidrains/DALLE2-pytorch/blob/main/dalle2_pytorch/dalle2_pytorch.py), in line 295

`text = text[..., :5]`

I was wondering if it take the text list from index=0 to 5.

However, it didn't work, I tried to use `text = ["an oil painting of a corgi"]` as input, it shows error,  `string indices must be integers`

I am still confused about it, what the meaning of it?

Comment: That works for Numpy arrays. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: btw. you can click on the line in github to select it and have it referenced under the link: https://github.com/lucidrains/DALLE2-pytorch/blob/main/dalle2_pytorch/dalle2_pytorch.py#L295

Comment: @AKX Hi, I tried to use `text = np.array(["an oil painting of a corgi"])` as input, it still shows error, `'bool' object has no attribute 'cumsum'
`

Comment: @kosciej16 thanks, but I still have no idea about the format of input, what should I input if the code could work?

Comment: @4daJKong _What_ shows that error?

Comment: @AKX `text = np.array(["an oil painting of a corgi"]) `  `text = text[..., :5]`   `print(text)`

Comment: This is not valid Python. I'm adding the [tag:numpy] tag, where this is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: @4daJKong those 3 lines definitely do _not_ raise `'bool' object has no attribute 'cumsum'` on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to make it work? As syntax you wrote takes first 5 rows from every column, you could fill column with rows, where every row is a letter:

```
res = np.array(list("an oil painting of a corgi"))
print(res[..., :5])
```

Is there any python magic behind? Not really, everything can be easily achieved by us:

```
class MyClass:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # ofc key could be just a single value
        a, b = key
        if a is Ellipsis:
            if isinstance(b, slice):
                print("HA!")


res = MyClass()
res[..., :5]
```